# is there a way to implement nearby pharmacy project with geodjango

Tags: django, geodjango

first time using geodjango, I search a way to implement nearby locations with geodjango.
i already create a postgres/postgis database,here is what i try:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis import geos

class pharmacie(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  location = models.PointField(null=True) # Spatial Field Types

  objects = models.Manager()
  def __str__(self) -> str:
    return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance

pharmacie.objects.annotate(
    distance=Distance('location', user_location)
).order_by('distance').first()
```

That will return the nearest pharmacy to the user_location